# Opening Mongo Shell using Chef

Tags: mongodb, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, mongo-shell

I am using chef scripts to install mongo, configure the replication and run some db initialize scripts (load("initializeScript.js"))

Mongo gets installed without any issue now but for configuring the replica members I need open mongo shell and  run commands like:

```
rs.initiate() and rs.add("SERVER DETAILS")
```

I am trying to do it this way

```
 mongo_shell_command = 'mongo -ssl --sslPEMKeyFile ' +node['mongo']['ssl']['dir'] +node['hostname'] + '.pem --sslCAFile ' + node['mongo']['ssl']['dir'] + node['mongo']['cert'] + ' --sslAllowInvalidHostnames'

execute 'mongo_shell' do
        command mongo_shell_command
    end

    execute 'mongo_replicaSet' do
        command "mongo --eval rs.execute()"
        only_if { ::File.exist?(node['mongo']['config']) }
    end
execute 'initialize_db' do
             command "mongo --eval \"load(\"initializeScript.js\")\""
            cwd node['mongo']['script']['dir']
        end
```

But this fails.

Is there any other way to open mongo shell using chef and execute these commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R & D, I figured the way to do so.

1. No need to specifically open mongo shell.
2. use --eval in the end and directly run the command.
3. Need to provide delay between
   resources because the initialization takes a few seconds in mongo.

Comment: Note: A single quote is needed to run function for example `command "mongo --eval 'db.serverStatus().storageEngine'"`

Answer (score 0):

What you have there could be cleaned up a bit, but overall you have the right idea. You can pass in a file of commands to run so rather then using `load()` you can just do `mongo initializeScript.js`. And you might want to combine all three initialization commands in to one thing just for simplicity, but that's up to you.